# What are the proper permissions for production use of wp cli

Tags: wp-cli

I am running several instances of WP on GCP VMs and a test VM setup with Ubuntu 22.04 / PHP8.1 and followed the instructions at https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/ to install wp cli.

The wp info output is https://paste.gnome.org/RMjEypZZJ

Running the commands as-is has read and execute but no write permissions. I tried sudo as that struck me as the thing to do but there was a nice notice about security waiting for that and when I persisted it produced a cache write error.

Following advice from other resources I created a group with apache and the current user and gave it wxr on the web root and made the current user owner and that had mixed results. sudo -u www-data works but that seems like a workaround and not the proper usage.

My question is about the exact proper permissions to maintain security and use the wp cli as intended without workarounds. Thank you.

PHP CLI works fine without these permission issues which is why I'm confused because wp cli is a phar file operating from PHP.

Comment: the paste in your question was deleted/garbage collected and can't be accessed anymore can you fix it? Avoid linking offsite for debugging information and keep as much as possible in your question. Remember these questions aren't just for you they're for everybody else who might have this problem too (including future you).

Answer (score 2):

In *nix environments, the permissions and privileges of a running executable are determined by the user who executes the program. You've verified this by noticing that when you run wp-cli with sudo, what it can do changes - you didn't need to change the permissions on the executable to do this, you ran the program as root and the executable took root's privileges. This is also understandable as when you're logged in as a different user, the same executables can do different things - it's the user running the executable that changed, not the executable.

(I also note that install instructions for wp-cli don't mention anything specific re. privileges, and would if they needed to. https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/guides/installing/ )

There are exceptions to this, the setuid (Set User ID) or setgid (Set Group ID) bits allow an executable take the permissions of the user or group that owns the executable, but this is probably not required here.

So, it sounds like if wp-cli does not have permission to write a file when you run it as a particular user, assuming you haven't used the setuid or setgid bits, then you may want to double double check that the user you're running it as actually has the permissions required for wp-cli to write a file, or do whatever it needs to. I suspect this is the case.

The approach here to solve your issue would be to simulate what wp-cli is doing using the user you're running it as. E.g. if you get an error that wp-cli can't write to a file in directory `/var/www/foo/wp-bar`, then the first thing to do is e.g. `touch /var/www/foo/wp-bar/test`, and this should also give the same permissions error, then resolve this using whatever setup makes sense for you in terms of the user you're running wp-cli as and apache both having write permissions to those files. SO/SE will abound with help with that, e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115979/apache-permissions-to-allow-both-user-and-web-server-to-edit-var-www

(Edit: If this approach doesn't work, then post the error from wp-cli, and the error you get from manually carrying out a similar operation using the user you ran wp-cli as, and that should give extra info to be able to resolve, however that's a general Linux permissions issue rather than specific to WP)

Comment: Hey Moz, while I appreciate you want to help me find my own answer, and I really appreciate your time, but this is going to be for production sites and so I can't use your suggested strategy. I am looking for authoritative information that is lacking from the official documentation to solve this problem in a peer-reviewed sort of way.

Comment: @Richard The answer addressed your question, which was erroneous in its assumption that there's some wp-cli setup you're missing. There isn't, the docs reflect this, this is a user permissions issue and you have a misunderstanding about permissions. If you're look for a more 'professional' answer, that would be you definitely should not be using dev tools like wp-cli in a prod environment. You should be using those dev/staging side and have a CI or build environment where your prod server is only running prod code in a much more controlled environment than one you would be running wp-cli in.

Comment: Please understand that I am looking for answers from those who have actual experience with wp cli and proper implementation. Using anecdotal references may result in unintended side effects and consequences or may be out of step with the wp cli roadmap or intention which would then break the installation further down the road. To avoid all these pitfalls, I would prefer the answers to be from someone with first-hand knowledge of all of the software and platforms mentioned in my query.

Comment: `first-hand knowledge` Have you tried contacting the author of WP CLI? Contacting the author and reading the source-code would be the only first-hand knowledge. You could also open up an issue on [their Github](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues). Hopefully, with the above, you're able to find the help you're looking for. I'm also aware this isn't the first answer you've received pointing to permissions, it may be worth taking a step back and assessing your setup and approach.

Comment: Please refrain from bickering. I am clearly not looking for just anything that gives some instant relief. This isn't a crisis and I and looking for information from someone with first hand experience to answer. I removed my GitHub query because I do not have sufficient information to post on GitHub at this time. Thank you.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, My question is exactly about permissions, so I'm not sure why your comment is based on my disagreement with that. The problem is using the CORRECT permission scheme, not just any persmissions that allow me to rampage through with no care or thought. This question wasn't about just getting any result, it was about find the proper solution.  Furthermore, I never received any answers or even actual help. Not here or on stack. What I received was argumentative behaviour, invalidating my question, and basically just trying to run me off. You are supposed to be preventing that.

Answer (score 1):

**It's not WP CLI** but the user that it's run as. Using `sudo` will give `root` level user access which explains why you can use `sudo wp`.

If using `wp` without `sudo` fails with read/write permission errors then the problem is that the user running the command is unable to read/write those files and folders. *That it's WP CLI you first encountered this with is unfortunate coincidence and not something specific to WordPress or WP CLI.*

Steps to take:

- run `whoami` to determine the user who is executing WP CLI
- run `groups` to determine the user groups you're in.
- Use `ls -al` to identify the owner and group of the files that it's struggling to write to

Either the user returned by `whoami` or one of the groups returned by `groups` needs to match with the files and folders returned by `ls -al`. Usually this is a `www-data` type user group, but if they do not match then the user can't read/write/execute, not unless the permissions on those files say that the *public* can do those things. That's how permissions are meant to work:

[image]

Where here:

- owner is the person who owns the file you're trying to modify. Can the owner of the file read/write/execute it?
- group is the user group that owns the file, can users who are members of that group read/write/execute it?
- public is everyone else who isn't the above, can they read/write/execute it?

It's likely that you've correctly set those files to not be writable to by public. Most users, unaware of groups, would mistakenly try to set `777` aka everyone can do everything, but the correct course of action is to ensure your SSH/terminal user is in the appropriate user groups.

Ideally your Apache/PHP workers are running as their own user, and that user and your terminal user are both in a `www-data` user group or equivalent so that they can both access the files, but the Apache workers/PHP have limited system access.

This is also why we can't tell you what the correct permissions are, because the answer depends on who is asking and the specific system you're asking about! The answer for me might be very different to you.